# type time in hh:mm format in jsf

Tags: jsf, input, time, richfaces

The date format contains `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` which can be used in this manner using 
    `<rich:calendar datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"

    value="#{uCBController.uCBUnit2.ucbEsp.lastSD}"` button.
but this gives option to modify only date (and may be along with time.)

But what I want is when select this button , it should display only time to select and modify, and saves in time format only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two `<rich:inputNumberSlider>` components (one for picking the hours and one for picking the minutes). `<rich:calendar>` doesn't support picking only the time.

```
<rich:inputNumberSpinner value="#{bean.hours}" minValue="0" maxValue="23" />
<rich:inputNumberSpinner value="#{bean.minutes}" minValue="0" maxValue="59" />
```

Then, in the managed bean, just create two properties with the correspoding accessors.

```
public class Bean {
  private Integer hours;

  private Integer minutes;

  //getters, setters
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @kocko, but which will be better among the two -

    <h:inputText value="#{uCBController.conveyorTime}">
       <f:convertDateTime pattern="HH:mm"/>
    </h:inputText>
and the one that is yours.

Comment: I would do it with the approach in my answer, but of corse, this is a matter of choice based on the needs.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Actually I have tried this method, but it is putting them row wise, not all in one row.

    <rich:inputNumberSpinner inputSize="2" minValue="00" maxValue="24" value="#{conveyorTime.hours}"/>
                        <h:outputText value=":"/>
                        <rich:inputNumberSpinner inputSize="2" minValue="00" maxValue="60" value="#{conveyorTime.minutes}"/>